# How do I ":set prompt" by default for a particular program?

Tags: command-line, prompt, haskell

I'm new to Linux. I installed Haskell and was going through a tutorial, which showed me I can `:set prompt "ghci> "` to change the prompt.  I like the way this looks.  How can I make it so that Haskell uses this prompt by default, so I don't have to set it to be that every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `:set prompt "ghci> "` to ~/.ghci

Comment: `ghci` also advised me to do `chmod go-w ~/.ghci`. (Error: `*** WARNING: /home/barend/.ghci is writable by someone else, IGNORING! Suggested fix: execute 'chmod go-w /home/barend/.ghci'`)